# Tumblr API - how to get posts of a private blog using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, oauth, tumblr

I get a library named "tumblrwks" ( https://github.com/arkxu/tumblrwks ) that connect to the tumblr API using nodejs and i works, but the problem is i want get them form a private blog and for that i need the OAuth request.

How i can get the OAuth ( oauth_token & oauth_secret ) in Tumblr ?

this is the code that i want to complet with the OAuth, please help me

```
var Tumblr = require('tumblrwks');

/*
  You can get the consumerKey and consumerSecret by registing a tumblr app: http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps
*/

var tumblr = new Tumblr(
  {
    consumerKey: 'YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY',
    consumerSecret: 'YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET',
    accessToken: 'ACCESS_TOKEN',
    accessSecret: 'ACCESS_SECRET'
  }, "void2012.tumblr.com"
  // specify the blog url now or the time you want to use
);

tumblr.get('/info', {hostname: 'void2012.tumblr.com'}, function(json){
  console.log(json);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should go register an application on tumblr by going to http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps.

Once you complete the registration, you'll get your api key.

From http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2:

> You'll need this to get your API key, even if you don't ever need to
>   use a fully signed OAuth request

Comment: Yes, i did this instructions before and i need to have OAuth request to get posts in a private blog